# How do I use WLSDisparityFilter and ximgproc from OpenCV on Android?

Tags: android, opencv, stereo-3d, vision

The official [opencv android builds](https://opencv.org/platforms/android/) do not contain the [opencv_contrib](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib) modules and building them yourself is not trivial.  Luckily we don't have to do the building thanks to [chaoyangnz](https://github.com/chaoyangnz/opencv3-android-sdk-with-contrib).

However, with those builds there are no JNI definitions for creating [WLSDisparityFilter](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.3/d9/d51/classcv_1_1ximgproc_1_1DisparityWLSFilter.html) objects so, although the underlying ximgproc libraries are there, you can't actually create a WLS filter for [filtering stereo depth maps](https://docs.opencv.org/3.3.1/d3/d14/tutorial_ximgproc_disparity_filtering.html).

How can you use WLSDisparityFilter on Android?

Answer (score 1):

Thankfully, the underlying libraries are present so you can use them simply by adding the java interface.

Open the: `/src/main/java/org/opencv/ximgproc/DisparityWLSFilter.java` file.

Add the following method:

```
    public DisparityWLSFilter createDisparityWLSFilter(StereoMatcher matcher_left) {
        DisparityWLSFilter filter = createDisparityWLSFilter_0(matcher_left);

        return filter;
    }
```

That's it!  Now you can create and use WLSDisparity filters.  Note, you'll have to use the full version of the `filter` function.  Something like this in Kotlin:

```
val disparityWLSFilter = createDisparityWLSFilter(stereoSGBM)
disparityWLSFilter.lambda = PrefHelper.getLambda()
disparityWLSFilter.sigmaColor = PrefHelper.getSigma()
disparityWLSFilter.filter(disparityMatLeft, leftMat, 
    disparityMatFiltered, disparityMatRight, Rect(0, 0, 
    disparityMatLeft.cols(), disparityMatLeft.rows()), rightMat)
```

I am only using this module from opencv_contrib, although I imagine other missing ximgproc functions and other contrib modules could be enabled in much the same way.

Hopefully this helps someone else turn chunky, pixel-y disparity maps into beautiful depth maps!